# PHPMailer is causing long cc strings to separate

Tags: phpmailer, html-email, email

I use PHPMailer to send HTML emails. The code looks as follows:

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;       // 3 = Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->setFrom($mgr_email);
        $mail->addReplyTo($mgr_email);
        $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        // $legacy is an array we loop through of emails
        $first = true;
        foreach ($legacy as $x => $theiremail) {
            if ($first == true) {
                $mail->addAddress(trim($theiremail));
                $first = false;
            } else {
                $mail->AddCC(trim($theiremail));
            }
        }

        ...

        // later, we add an image every time (the company logo)
        $mail->addEmbeddedImage($paths[$i]['path'], $paths[$i]['cid'], "image$i.jpg");
```

However, when I have many recipients, the email address string starts to break with a space in them, and always around the same spot. Example:

`george@george.com, anyone@anyone.com, example@example.com, steven@we bsite.com`

Steven here does not get the email. I've experienced something like this in HTML once where our longer emails just needed a space somewhere because our "headers" were a long, single word, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this with PHPMailer. In that case, all I had to do was add a space somewhere in the code. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're sending with `isMail()` (the default sending mechanism), and there are some potential issues surrounding line breaks when using that. Can you try using SMTP to localhost instead? Do this: `$mail->isSMTP(); $mail->Host = 'localhost';`

Comment: That's a start; emails are still sending after putting your two lines in. :} Time to wait and see. Thank you.

Comment: Well, looks like that did it. Shame that wasn't your answer, I'd like to accept and 'complete' this question! With an explanation of why that worked would be nice too, for extra googlability.